# Flatten dataframe for non element values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, explode, flatten

Below is my data structure:

```
root    
 |-- platform_build_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pro: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- av: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- avc: string (nullable = true)
```

i tried using explode function

```
val flattened = Data_df.withColumn("pro", explode(array($"pro")))
```

this will work if there is an element inside `pro` column, but in my case what should i use to get this data into flattened format.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`.select()`** with struct column **`(pro.*)`** will result flatten format.

```
Data_df.select("platform_build_id","pro.*").show()
```

**Example:**

```
val s_ds=Seq("""{"platform_build_id":"1234","pro":{"av":"pro_av","avc":"pro_avc"}}""").toDS

spark.read.json(s_ds).printSchema

//root
// |-- platform_build_id: string(nullable = true)
// |-- pro: struct (nullable = true)
// |    |-- av: string (nullable = true)
// |    |-- avc: string (nullable = true)

spark.read.json(s_ds).select("platform_build_id","pro.*").show()
```

***Result:***

```
+-----------------+------+-------+
|platform_build_id|    av|    avc|
+-----------------+------+-------+
|             1234|pro_av|pro_avc|
+-----------------+------+-------+
```

Comment: @toofrellik, Did the answer helped? If yes accept the answer to close the thread :)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work